# Hibernate: cascade create object from Map field (Map.key)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, collections, spring-annotations, mapkeyjoincolumn

I have in Class a field Map<Object, String> type. How can I save Object's from Map when parent Class object save?
I understand whats the problem, but cant solve it. I cant place annotation @***ToMany to indicate cascade = ALL, talk `targets the type 'java.lang.String' which is not an '@Entity' type`, I think thats apply annotation on map.value.
Tell me the right way, please.

Thanks a lot.

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Profile {
....
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="addressId", referencedColumnName = "addressId")
    @Column(name = "description")
    @CollectionTable(name = "ProfileAddress",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "profileId", referencedColumnName = "profileId")})
    private Map<Address, String> addresses; //String it's description for address - "home", "work" etc. I want separate table with parentObjectId, addressId, description. And need that create/delete/update Address object's with Parent object together.
```

Address is Entity of course.

Error:
`object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`

Comment: this seems to be a `@ManyToMany` relationship not `@OneToMany`

Comment: Try @ManyToMany with cascade persist

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Profile {
....

      @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,  CascadeType.MERGE})
      @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="addressId", referencedColumnName = "addressId")
      @JoinTable(name = "ProfileAddress",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "profileId", referencedColumnName = "profileId"),  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "description")))
      private Map<Address, String> addresses;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but an error occurs in application start: Association '...entity.Profile.addresses' targets the type 'java.lang.String' which is not an '@Entity' type. Already I tried ManyToMany, but with one cascade = CascadeType.ALL, the same result.

Comment: So cascade is not way. It's description from attribute cascade: (Optional) The operations that must be cascaded to the target of the association.
When the target collection is a java.util.Map, the cascade element applies to the map value.
Defaults to no operations being cascaded.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#map-collections) says

`when the map value is a basic type or embeddable class, the ElementCollection annotation is used`.

As your map value is the basic type String, I assume `@ElementCollection` is the annotation you should use.